# Are Reddit personalized RSS feeds reliable?

Tags: rss, reddit

I just subscribed to a personalized feed of all my Reddit subscriptions yesterday.

It doesn't seem to be very reliable though. Perhaps it's only updated once every X hours? Several times, I found items on my Reddit that have posted hours ago, but did not show up on the feed.

[What's up with that?](http://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/kjv0r/personalized_reddit_rss_feeds_stopped_working/)

Comment: lol, when I tried to register on the specific feed for http://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/kjv0r/personalized_reddit_rss_feeds_stopped_working/, I got `The feed being requested cannot be found.` Are reddit feeds generally broken?

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I sign up for a Reddit personalized front page RSS feed (using Google Reader), I find that it generates one front page's worth of links once, and then only refreshes every few weeks. When it does refresh, it brings up links that have only a few upvotes, rather than the front page.